# RandomSiteControls, Version=7.1.5200.1, uses Telerik.Sitefinity which has a higher version than referenced assembly Telerik.Sitefinity

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I m getting following error while trying to add RandomSiteControls to my project.How to fix below error?

" CS1705: Assembly 'RandomSiteControls, Version=7.1.5200.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Telerik.Sitefinity, Version=7.1.5202.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b28c218413bdf563' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Telerik.Sitefinity, Version=7.1.5200.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b28c218413bdf563' "

I am using sitefinity version 7.1.5200.0

Comment: What is RandomSiteControls?

Comment: @Veselin Vasilev  -- It is a dll for adding TabControls in sitefinity. I have found it on the following link http://www.sitefinitysteve.com/downloads

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the errors, you can either [add some assembly bindings](http://www.sitefinitysteve.com/blog/code/2012/03/24/sitefinity-how-to-list#Avoid%20Version%20errors%20with%20Assembly%20Binding) to your web.config or download a different version of the RamdonSiteControls that was built against those particular Sitefinity dlls.

You can find the version for 7.1.5200 [here](http://www.sitefinitysteve.com/downloads/randomsitecontrols/7-1-5200-0).